# Button relative to middle button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the news button and the play button to touch the middle home button so they always have a preset distance from the middle, but I don't know how.

css:

```
#homebutton {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
margin-left: -133px;
margin-right: -133px;
left: 50%;
top: 196px;
}

#newsbutton {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
margin-left: -125px;
margin-right: -125px;
left: 34%;
top: 196px;
}

#playbutton{
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
margin-left: -125px;
margin-right: -125px;
right: 34%;
top: 196px;
}
```

html:

```
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/nYFGA55.png" id= "playbutton" onmouseover= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/5bFu4zm.png'" onmouseout= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/nYFGA55.png'">
</img>
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/VNaqgtL.png" id= "newsbutton" onmouseover= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/rMDNaaM.png'" onmouseout= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/VNaqgtL.png'">
</img>
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/rq2W4TA.png" id= "homebutton" onmouseover= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/yJClibn.png'" onmouseout= "this.src= 'http://i.imgur.com/rq2W4TA.png'">
</img>
```

the site itself:
http://gentexcodes.com/

Comment: Side note, image elements are self-closing. There is no `</img>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to add a container and use `text-align: center` to center the buttons inside it. If you make the 'home' button the middle button in the markup, this is a very easy solution. Since the buttons are images anyway, you can use `font-size: 0` on the container to remove the whitespace between the buttons. You could do this in markup too by removing whitespace between the closing `>` and the opening `<` of the next button.

I've removed the hover effect for brevity, shrunk the buttons to not mess up the smaller inline runnable code snippet, and added a border to show clearly that the buttons are touching. This shouldn't change the general solution though.

```css
.buttonbar {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonbar">

<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/nYFGA55.png" id="playbutton" class="button">
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/rq2W4TA.png" id="homebutton" class="button">
<img src= "http://i.imgur.com/VNaqgtL.png" id="newsbutton" class="button">
  
</div>
```

Personally, I wouldn't use img tags for this at all, since semantically it doesn't make much sense. I'd choose an `<a href>` that would link to the right page. Then, through CSS, you could hide the text in it (or make it transparent), set a background image, and set another background image when the element is hovered. That way, you have a page that is cleaner, easier to maintain, fully operational without JavaScript and CSS, properly styled (with hover-effect) without JavaScript, and that is semantically correct, indexible by search engines and usable by screen readers and other tools for the visually impaired.

But that's just an opinion. ;)